# how to stop bootstrap container going under address bar

Tags: bootstrap-4, leaflet, containers

I have the following bootstrap container being displayed in leaflet. I can drag the container around the screen, if I move it to far up the screen the container disappears under the address bar and if I unclick it drops there and I can't get it back (same problem for moving in any direction of the screen extremities). Is there a way to make sure the container stays within the leaflet display?

Thank you.

```
<div id="vContainer" class="container-fluid scrollBox fluidCentrePosition" style="display:none" title="titleV"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div id="vTree"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="margin: auto; width: 95%;">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <button id="vTreeCheckAll" class="gj-button-md">Check All</button>
                <button id="vTreeUncheckAll" class="gj-button-md">Uncheck All</button>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

first image: within window [OK]
[image]
second image: has been dragged up and gone under address bar and cannot get it back once mouse released [NOT OK]
[image]

Comment: You need to restrict drop zone. Try this logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394538/restrict-drop-areas-to-some-draggable-elements And if it doesn't help share more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean with *address-bar* the browser adress-bar or a own one from your html?

If you talk about an address-bar from your html, it sounds like you need to add an higher `z-Index` to the container then the address-bar has.

Add in your css:

```
.vContainer {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

if `z-index: 1` doesn't work, try it with a higher value like `9999999`

Comment: thanks. It goes under the the browser address bar. The z-index hasn't worked with either 1 or a higher value. Added images to original post, when dragging Select V (vContainer) it leaves the screen in all directions which is not desired.